# Android - Centering GridView

Tags: android, xml, gridview

here I am with next question.

I want to center my GridView, I was searching answer on the web for couple hours and I saw that one of the soulutions would be to put my GridView in Relative Layout and then center it with android:layout_centerVertical="true" attribute bot it is not working :(

Can you please take a look at the code and give me some feedback? (this problem is regarding second GridView, id: tutorTypeGridView)

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/tutorSignupLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".activity.SignupStepOneActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/additionalInfoTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="@string/signup_step_one_under_welcome"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/additionalInfoTextView" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/chooseProfessionTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="39dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Choose your profession" />

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/professionGridView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/profession_buttons"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="6dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:verticalSpacing="6dp" >

    </GridView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/chooseTutorType"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="39dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Choose your profession" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/tutorTypeGridView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/tutor_types_buttons"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="6dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:verticalSpacing="6dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >

    </GridView>

    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it by creating a new function which calculates padding needed to center GridView, here it is: (bear in mind that I'm using it in Fragment)

```
    public void centerGridView(GridView gridView) {

    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);

    int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;

    int girdWidth = gridView.getWidth();

    int padding = width - girdWidth;

    padding = convertPxToDp(padding);

    gridView.setPadding(padding / 2, 0, padding / 2, 0);

}

    public int convertPxToDp(int px){
    return Math.round(px/(getResources().getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().xdpi/DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use `android:layout_centerInParent=“true”`
It needs to be in RelativeLayout

Comment: Yes, getting "Invalid layout param in a Linear Layout" error

EDIT: Maybe I shouldn't use Constraint Layout?

EDIT2: Nope, that's not the case

Comment: Don’t use RelativeLayout inside LinearLayout , use it after </LinearLayout>